# Asyncio with boto and for range?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, python-asyncio, boto

I'm trying first time the [asyncio botocore implementation](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiobotocore). However, I'm quite sure I'm not getting the expected asynchronicity, likely due to my own lack of experience with it. :)

The goal of the bellow method is to **duplicate all files in a bucket while suffixing keys with UUIDs**.

```python
async def async_duplicate_files_in_bucket(bucket,
                                          how_many_times=1):
    session = get_session()

    async with session.create_client('s3') as s3_client:
        s3_client: S3Client

        paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects')
        async for result in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket):

            for file in result["Contents"]:
                # it already includes the prefix in the same
                original_file_name: str = file["Key"]
                logger.debug(f"Duplicating file: {original_file_name} ")

                for _ in range(how_many_times):
                    new_file_name = original_file_name + "_" + uuid.uuid4().__str__()
                    copy_source = {
                        'Bucket': bucket,
                        'Key': original_file_name
                    }

                    await s3_client.copy_object(Bucket=bucket,
                                                CopySource=copy_source,
                                                Key=new_file_name)
                    print("-", end="")
```

When looking at the terminal:

1. I see `Duplicating file: file_1` not moving to the next file until it finishes duplicating `file_1`. Just then it I get a new log line with `Duplicating file: file_2`.
2. `print('-', end="")` is not printing

Given my little experience with `asyncio`, I hypothesize that the `for _ in range(how_many_times)` is blocking the event loop.

Appreciate directions to better understand how to make use of `asyncio` in Python as well as to achieve the goal of the function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not blocking the event loop. What you *are* doing is not making proper use of `asyncio` concurrency!

Using the `asyncio.gather()` helper allows you to run a number of async operations in parallel.

In this example, we buffer all desired `copy_object` operations in a big list, then run them all in parallel in a single huge batch:

```
async def async_duplicate_files_in_bucket(bucket, how_many_times=1):
    session = get_session()

    s3_client: S3Client
    async with session.create_client("s3") as s3_client:
        awaitables: list[Awaitable[Any]] = []
        paginator = s3_client.get_paginator("list_objects")
        async for result in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket):

            for file in result["Contents"]:
                # it already includes the prefix in the same
                original_file_name: str = file["Key"]
                logger.debug(f"Duplicating file: {original_file_name} ")

                for _ in range(how_many_times):
                    new_file_name = original_file_name + "_" + uuid.uuid4().__str__()
                    copy_source = {"Bucket": bucket, "Key": original_file_name}

                    awaitable = s3_client.copy_object(
                        Bucket=bucket,
                        CopySource=copy_source,
                        Key=new_file_name,
                    )
                    awaitables.append(awaitable)
                    print("-", end="")

        await asyncio.gather(*awaitables)
```

Depending on the number of results in your paginator, you might want to run several batches, one per paginator page. This would use less memory, as you're only buffering one one page of `copy_object` operations at a time. It also limits the concurrency a bit, which might perform better (or worse!):

```
async def async_duplicate_files_in_bucket(bucket, how_many_times=1):
    session = get_session()

    s3_client: S3Client
    async with session.create_client("s3") as s3_client:
        
        paginator = s3_client.get_paginator("list_objects")
        async for result in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket):
            awaitables: list[Awaitable[Any]] = []

            for file in result["Contents"]:
                # it already includes the prefix in the same
                original_file_name: str = file["Key"]
                logger.debug(f"Duplicating file: {original_file_name} ")

                for _ in range(how_many_times):
                    new_file_name = original_file_name + "_" + uuid.uuid4().__str__()
                    copy_source = {"Bucket": bucket, "Key": original_file_name}

                    awaitable = s3_client.copy_object(
                        Bucket=bucket,
                        CopySource=copy_source,
                        Key=new_file_name,
                    )
                    awaitables.append(awaitable)
                    print("-", end="")

            await asyncio.gather(*awaitables)
```

You can make even smaller batches, one per `how_many_times` group too. This will have an even lower memory footprint (and concurrency):

```
async def async_duplicate_files_in_bucket(bucket, how_many_times=1):
    session = get_session()

    s3_client: S3Client
    async with session.create_client("s3") as s3_client:
        
        paginator = s3_client.get_paginator("list_objects")
        async for result in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket):
            for file in result["Contents"]:
                # it already includes the prefix in the same
                original_file_name: str = file["Key"]
                logger.debug(f"Duplicating file: {original_file_name} ")

                awaitables: list[Awaitable[Any]] = []
                for _ in range(how_many_times):
                    new_file_name = original_file_name + "_" + uuid.uuid4().__str__()
                    copy_source = {"Bucket": bucket, "Key": original_file_name}

                    awaitable = s3_client.copy_object(
                        Bucket=bucket,
                        CopySource=copy_source,
                        Key=new_file_name,
                    )
                    awaitables.append(awaitable)
                    print("-", end="")

                await asyncio.gather(*awaitables)
```

I'd suggest benchmarking all approaches and see what works best for you. Even the last example, with the lowest concurrency, should perform better than your original code!

**See also:** [asyncio.gather() docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather)

Comment: Thanks. Why did you put the gather outside the paginator loop? Does it mean the gather will run `then` only after all page promises are returned? How does it differ from running gather inside the `result[contents]` loop (or maybe the range loop)?

Comment: An excellent question! You could gather batches of tasks for each page in the paginator, for sure. That's what I meant to imply with "something more intelligent with batching".

Comment: Thanks. Can you please elaborate a little about what the place I choose for gathering impacts variable dependencies and async concurrency?

Comment: I've added two more examples with successively smaller batches, and explained how they affect memory usage and concurrency. But this is something you'd have to benchmark! 